# Navigating RepeatBox in code

Tags: smartface.io

In my Smartface app I have a dataset binded to a RepeatBox.
I am adding new row to the dataset from a function that is running  ASYNCRONOUSLY.
I can perfectly see my new row within the RepeatBox but it does not scroll automatically to the new row. If all visible rows of the RepeatBox are filled then new rows come off the screen which is not very user-friendly.
Is there any way to move the RepeatBox to the last row (or to the top row)?

P.S.: moving binded dataset by seek() doesn't help - the RepeatBox stands still

Answer (score 1):

Try this : 
RepeatBox.setTopIndex(0, itemIndex, 100);

Use itemIndex as a variable that is incremented each time you add a new row to the dataset. You can calculate how many numbers of rows do you have, make the variable start from that number, not 0.

The values 0 and 100 can be changed according to your design. You can check the links below for information about repeatbox's properties and members : 
http://docs.smartface.io/html/M_SMF_UI_RepeatBox_setTopIndex.htm
http://docs.smartface.io/html/AllMembers_T_SMF_UI_RepeatBox.htm